# Julia: Transforming an Array of Arrays in a 2-dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an Array `d` that contains an Array of floats:

```
julia> d
99-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
...
```

I'm trying to convert it into a 2-dimensional Array, and I sucessfully achieved my goal with:

```
data = Array(Float64,length(d),length(d[1]))
for i in 1:length(d)
    for j in 1:length(d[1])
        data[i,j] = d[i][j]
    end
end
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`hcat(d...)` and `vcat(d...)` should do what you want.

Comment: @scry Can you elaborate? The question is about converting a 1d array of 1d arrays to a 2d array. The prescribed method works.

Comment: I just want to note that the `...` is significant here, it will [splat](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/faq/#what-does-the-operator-do) the arguments to the function (thank you @MattB). I wrote (and deleted) a misleading answer because I didn't know they were to be used literally.

Comment: Also, to get a matrix in the same shape, take the transpose of the result of hcat: `hcat(d...)'`

Comment: Or just use ``vcat(d...)`` instead.

Comment: `vcat` gives me a "flattened" one-dimensional array - unless I'm missing something, it's not equivalent.

Comment: Oops! Sorry! Definitely my mistake.

Answer (score 6):

If your array of array is supposed to represent a matrix and you want to preserve the logic, then this is the simpler I found (julia 1.1)

```
julia> a=[ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]
 [5, 6]

julia> permutedims(reshape(hcat(a...), (length(a[1]), length(a))))
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
```

One could use `transpose` instead of `permutedims`.